# how to use ftp in tortoise svn checkout?

Tags: svn, networking, ftp, tortoisesvn, filezilla

I want to connect svn tortoise with FTP server which i created using FileZilla.
I am trying create a local repository in my system where others can access my FTP server to commit the files using SVN Tortoise.

[image]
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXCai.png)

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN is a Subversion client, not an FTP client. You need to use Subversion server if you want to access repositories remotely. Therefore, the question itself does not make any sense.